# How to parse this shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

I have a shortcode like this `[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/67658191" params="" width=" 100%" height="166" iframe="true" /]`

How can I get the content of the URL part or extract the whole shortcode in a post and then display it?

`do_shortcode` doesn't help a lot.

I want to use that shortcode in my theme and since the URL part is dynamic I have difficulty of having it display dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

[`shortcode_parse_atts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_parse_atts) will give you managable information.

```
  $atts = shortcode_parse_atts(
    '[soundcloud url="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/67658191" params="" width=" 100%" height="166" iframe="true" /]'
  );
```

You will get an array that looks like this:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "[soundcloud"
  ["url"]=>
  string(41) "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/67658191"
  ["params"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["width"]=>
  string(5) " 100%"
  ["height"]=>
  string(3) "166"
  ["iframe"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "/]"
}
```

You can the do something like:

```
  var_dump($atts);  // dump everything
  echo $atts['url']; // echo just the URL
```

I don't understand the context you want to use this in. I think you've left out a fair bit of explanation.

Comment: Thank you.I just want to use it in my theme.Extract the url part or maybe search that shortcode in a post and then display it.In brief,I want to show the shortcode in php files.OK...it maybe be a bit confusing

Comment: @s_ha_dum, is there any function to reverse this behaviour ? I have an array with shortcode name in `tag` key and attributes in `attr` key. I want to create a shortcode strign so that I can use `do_shortcode` with it later. I can manually do it, but wanted to know if there's a function in core.